# How to get object id of ParseUser in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

Out of the following methods, only the last one gives me the object id of the user where I convert the ParseUser to a JSON object then access that. Is there a nicer way to get the objectId?

```
console.log("GET objectId:" + request.user.get('objectId'));

console.log("objectId:" + request.user.objectId);

console.log("[objectId]: " + request.user["objectId"]);

console.log("toJSON: " + request.user.toJSON().objectId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get the user or any other parse object objectId in JavaScript you need to use **.id** and not .objectId 
In Parse JavaScript the objectId is saved under **id** property 
so you need to change your code to

```
console.log("GET objectId:" + request.user.id);
```

Comment: That sounds like what I was after, will try it out in a bit when I get a chance and let you know how I go :)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Cool. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse(request.user) to parse the data and then access properties or items from it. The way I use it is like below.

```
  var data = JSON.parse(response.data.Message);
   console.log(data.Id) \\Log Id in data object
```

Comment: Yeah, that is effectively what I do with the last option there (`request.user.toJSON().objectId`), but feels like there must be a nicer way than having to just parse the entire object as JSON first.